# The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream getting this error

Tags: c#, json

i am working on asp.net webform to passing json string on a url for authenticate but getting error in Gzip.

here is my method to post data

```
private static string GetResponse(string requestData, string url)
{
    string responseXML = string.Empty;
    try
    {

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        var rsp = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        if (rsp == null)
        {
            //throw exception
        }
        using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(rsp, CompressionMode.Decompress)))
        {
            responseXML = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(readStream.ReadToEnd()).InnerXml;
        }

    }
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        //get the response stream
        WebResponse response = webEx.Response;
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        String responseMessage = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
    }

    finally
    {

    }
    return responseXML.ToString();
}
```

getting this error while i am passing the json object and url

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaCJf.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure the response is gzip?  Just because you set the Accept-Encoding in the header doesn't guarantee the response is gzipped.  Lots of servers don't compress dynamic content unless explicitly turned on

Comment: You should check the Content-Encoding of the Response. may be it is not gzip